# Citadels: Does the crown switch hands if the king is killed?

Tags: citadels

In Citadels, Ann has the crown and Bill chooses the king. The assassin kills the king. Who keeps the crown at the end of the turn?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The King gets the crown when his character is revealed whether he is alive at that point or not.**

Otherwise the king would be exceptionally weak IMHO as whomever had the crown could continually pick the assassin, assassinate the king, keep the crown, and first pick the assassin again. You can argue that they should be assassinating other characters besides the king, but seeing as there are fewer yellow districts than any other color the King needs all the help he can get...

Comment: I am not sure it would be so bad >2p.  Be King, take Assassin, kill King will get dominated by someone with free reign over Merchant.

Comment: @RobRenaud True, maybe the still-crowned assassin would be wiser to pick a better target or choose a better character, but it still makes the King more of a last-pick as it doesn't even guarantee first pick later on. I do love it when I get to snag the architect and merchant while other players are busy fighting over the king, and making sure you get the crown regardless of assassination makes up for his otherwise lack of usefulness.

Answer (score 12):

The crown goes to the player that chose the **King** role card at the end of the round.

[Fantasy Flight Rule book](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Citadels/support/citadels-rules-english.pdf) (page 14).

> **4) King**
>
> ... If you are murdered, you skip your turn like any other character. Nevertheless, after the last player has played his turn, when it becomes known that you had the murdered King’s character card, you take the Crown (as the King’s heir).