# Does assassination nullify the bishop's protection?

Tags: citadels

If you are the bishop and you were assassinated, are you still protected from the warlord in that turn? I'm guessing you are, and [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6761/citadels-does-the-crown-switch-hands-if-the-king-is-killed) also hints that you are, but the rules are not clear so I wondered whether it really is the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the Bishop loses his protection when assassinated. From the last page of the [FAQ](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Citadels/support/citadels-faq.pdf&ei=9MtOULWBCYquiQLo94HYDA&usg=AFQjCNEKZSOanwjkek2W4yweizBtQBuiHg&sig2=s33ez6n3of3mmeDIPd7D1A)

> Q: Can the warlord destroy a building of a murdered Bishop?
>
> A: Yes. Since the Bishop is not present, he is not able to protect his districts.